# Variable definition for Invisible Text

Tags: emacs

I'm reading about [Invisible Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Invisible-Text.html#Invisible-Text) in the Elisp manual. It defines the variable `my-symbol` to add or not add `...` in place of the hidden text.

```
 ;; If you want to display an ellipsis:
 (add-to-invisibility-spec '(my-symbol . t))
 ;; If you don't want ellipsis:
 (add-to-invisibility-spec 'my-symbol)
```

However, I don't get it. How is it that you don't use `(setq my-symbol "...")`. What is the difference in syntax between `(setq my-symbol "...")` and `'(my-symbol . t)`.

This might be a silly question but I'm not an expert or anything in Lisp and I'm playing around with Emacs configurations.

Comment: I don't think this is really a lisp question, but more of an implementation detail. The `buffer-invisibility-spec` is handled at the C level and it assumes certain data structures, eg a cons cell or a single atomic value. Note that emacs text can have many properties associated with it, `describe-text-properties`. See docs for plists vs. alists

Comment: thanks for the hint @jenesaisquoi ! (still trying to figure out stuff and playing with the config file)

Answer (score 1):

If you were to do `(setq my-symbol  "...")` that would just set the value of variable `my-symbol` to that string.

What the Elisp manual is describing is the form of a specification, that is, a Lisp data structure (in this case a list) that causes certain parts of the buffer text to be invisible.  It causes that behavior because such a spec is handled by Emacs automatically.

As @jenesaisquoi said in a comment, it is the C code of Emacs that does that automatic handling of the buffer invisibility spec. To use the spec, refer to the Elisp manual, node [Invisible Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Invisible-Text.html).

Comment: Thanks @Drew, I think my problem is mainly that I have absolutely no idea how `'(my-symbol . t)` becomes some ellipses, which seems to me something counter-intuitive, or that at least something I haven't yet understood. I have a feeling that it's related to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) but I'm looking for the info in the Elisp manual as you said. I would like to know something as simple as to change "..." to "---" just to know how it works.

Comment: damn, I think I got it, so, the `. t` means dots equal true, and that's how it include ellipses. Sorry, as I said, lisp is not my forte. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: No, not at all. Do not try to interpret the buffer invisibility spec without reading about its form and interpretation, in the Elisp manual. See my answer update. The buffer-invisibility spec entry `(my-symbol . t)` is just a cons cell with symbol `my-symbol` as car and symbol `t` as cdr. The spec is *interpreted* by Emacs C code to do what the spec signifies declaratively. You won't understand that signification without reading the section of the manual.

Comment: If you want to dig deeper into the code as well, you could try using `xref-find-definitions` on the function, typically bound to `M-.` Assuming you have the C code, you will eventually arrive at the implementation. @silgon

Comment: I don't. I'll check it out and download it for my version. Thanks for the helk guys. I've been using emacs for a long time but I've always avoided programming in lisp, all my lisp init code has been extracted from somewhere and I just did a few easy tweaks. Now I want to use some custom stuff and I kind of struggle =)